# What causes WebView to fail loading PDFs inconsistently even with properly implemented code in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, webview

I am trying to load the pdf url to webview . using loadWebview function , using google docs view . but i cant be able to load it properly.

Here is the funtion , I made :

```
 @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    private fun loadWebView(serviceInfoUrl: String) {
        with(serviceInfoWebView.settings) {
            cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
            javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
            javaScriptEnabled = true
            domStorageEnabled = true
            loadWithOverviewMode = true
            useWideViewPort = true
            builtInZoomControls = true
            displayZoomControls = false
            setSupportZoom(true)
            setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
            val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
            cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(serviceInfoWebView, true)
            mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        }

        serviceInfoWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageCommitVisible(view: WebView, url: String) {
                super.onPageCommitVisible(view, url)
                serviceInfoProgressBarLayout.visibility = View.GONE
                serviceInfoWebView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onPageFinished(webView: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(webView, url)
//                webView?.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.querySelector('[class=\"ndfHFb-c4YZDc-q77wGc\"]').remove();})()")
                webView?.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {document.querySelector('[class=\"ndfHFb-c4YZDc-Wrql6b\"]').remove();})()")
            }
        }
        serviceInfoWebView.loadUrl(serviceInfoUrl)
    }
```

**Problem**

So the prolem is that sometime the pdf is loaded successfully but sometime the loader(progressbar i think it cant able to get the webview) keeps loading and sometime there is "No Perview Image" message comes and pdf does able to load properly , i think there will be some kind of para that i have to make it true . But i dont know the problem , some said it because of conectivity issue. Please explain me .

This how i called it.

```
loadWebView("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://example.gov.ae/-/file.pdf")
```